# Prediction interval around a gam

Tags: r, gam

I have a large data set that consists of thousands of measurements of length and weight. I have provided a subset of 500 observations here:

```
df <- structure(list(length_cm = c(24.7, 23.8, 21.9, 23.2, 23.5, 22.2, 
20.5, 22.6, 24, 21.6, 22.4, 21.2, 20.6, 23.1, 21.4, 23.1, 23.5, 
23, 21.8, 22.4, 23, 23.8, 24, 21, 23.4, 23.2, 21.6, 25.9, 22.1, 
30.6, 22.1, 21.7, 23.2, 21.1, 23.8, 23.2, 27.2, 23.8, 21.6, 21.1, 
21.7, 22.9, 23.3, 24.1, 22.7, 20.4, 22.5, 21.7, 23.2, 22.7, 20.6, 
23.7, 24.6, 23.5, 26.3, 23.6, 22.2, 23.6, 21.4, 23.3, 24.7, 24.4, 
21.8, 24.9, 22.2, 23.1, 25, 23.5, 22.5, 20.4, 23.9, 23.7, 24, 
24.2, 22.9, 36.4, 30, 26, 28.5, 27, 35.7, 24.3, 28.6, 29.8, 18.7, 
25.7, 34.7, 31.4, 23.4, 37.7, 26.7, 28.3, 30.8, 29.2, 27.2, 25.6, 
39, 35.1, 41.2, 35.7, 29.9, 25.7, 24.6, 24, 24.9, 31, 29.9, 29.4, 
25.4, 20.2, 27.8, 32.7, 23.4, 29.1, 26.3, 25.7, 26, 24.9, 26.3, 
31.5, 30.1, 25.9, 28.8, 37.9, 38.4, 21.5, 20.5, 21.3, 21.3, 20.9, 
20.8, 22.5, 22.4, 21.4, 16.8, 17.3, 22.7, 19.7, 21.2, 18.1, 23.5, 
18.1, 22, 18.5, 18.4, 19.2, 19.4, 19.9, 20.5, 18.6, 22.6, 20.9, 
20.7, 20.6, 20.6, 21.6, 23.7, 22.8, 22.9, 20.8, 21.3, 23.5, 21.1, 
21.6, 24, 21, 23.3, 20.3, 22.4, 23.7, 24.6, 20.7, 23.1, 22.6, 
22.7, 19.5, 23, 19.8, 21, 19.8, 19.8, 17.2, 21.8, 25.3, 21.3, 
19.2, 22.1, 24.5, 23.2, 22.6, 19, 22, 17.5, 19.9, 24.4, 23.7, 
19.9, 23, 20.5, 18.3, 23.2, 21.1, 20.4, 22.2, 19.7, 19.2, 24, 
23.3, 23.3, 19, 21.5, 22, 19.1, 23.7, 19.9, 21.2, 23, 27.3, 20.7, 
22, 19.3, 24.9, 18.2, 20, 19.3, 25, 18, 21.8, 23.4, 23.9, 25.2, 
18.5, 22.2, 24.6, 22, 20.4, 20.7, 21.7, 19.1, 23.1, 21.5, 21.2, 
20.6, 22.3, 22.8, 21.3, 21.6, 22, 23, 24.2, 21.3, 19.7, 18.8, 
20.9, 20.3, 22.3, 18.9, 19.9, 20.2, 23.9, 19.7, 19.5, 17.6, 23.1, 
20.4, 20, 19.7, 20.3, 21.2, 23.9, 24, 25.6, 23.9, 23.5, 20.5, 
30.8, 32.8, 28.4, 28.7, 28, 28.9, 29.8, 31, 31.7, 28.6, 28.7, 
28.7, 26.7, 24.6, 30, 36.5, 26.5, 32, 29.6, 30.7, 27.7, 24.1, 
29.8, 28.8, 26, 22.4, 24, 24.8, 22.7, 22.7, 23.8, 25.3, 32.3, 
26.8, 22.1, 24.2, 23.8, 25.3, 24.1, 22.6, 22.9, 24.4, 26.7, 24.4, 
24.7, 25, 23.7, 24.3, 22.3, 22.7, 20, 22.5, 24.5, 25.1, 24, 22, 
20, 21.9, 18.3, 19.9, 19.4, 23.5, 20.2, 20, 17.8, 20.5, 23.2, 
18.5, 21.2, 18.2, 19.1, 22.1, 18.3, 21.6, 19.5, 22.7, 23.6, 24.6, 
23.2, 24.4, 19.1, 22.8, 23, 18.8, 22.6, 19, 21.7, 20.8, 23.7, 
20.8, 20, 23.2, 22, 21.4, 20.6, 22.6, 23.8, 21, 26.4, 24.5, 32.6, 
36.1, 36, 31, 33.1, 31.3, 34.2, 41.9, 35.4, 33.9, 31.9, 29.3, 
34.2, 29.9, 36.4, 38.5, 30.7, 40.2, 34.1, 29.7, 37.8, 37.8, 35.3, 
39, 39.5, 34.1, 30.5, 33.3, 33.2, 36, 31.6, 35, 34.2, 33.1, 31.5, 
33.5, 33.7, 39, 33.2, 35, 34.1, 32.6, 36.2, 34.4, 31.7, 32, 37.5, 
31.5, 32.7, 31.7, 35.7, 32.4, 28.5, 33.7, 33.9, 33.6, 34, 32, 
29.8, 35, 36, 31.7, 32.5, 32, 31, 29.5, 33.4, 32.5, 26.5, 28, 
35.3, 26, 26.5, 38.9, 32.7, 36.4, 35.7, 27.7, 25.8, 25.3, 30.1, 
36, 33.4, 37, 33.6, 31.7, 29.7, 35.9, 28.5, 33.1, 33.9, 29, 36.5, 
35.5, 29.2, 37.3, 40.3, 35.7, 32.6, 38.8, 40, 38.9, 39, 33.3, 
33.5, 34.3, 38.8, 34.4, 36, 35.9, 35.1, 30.7, 38.1, 31.3, 35, 
36.3, 32.4, 32.3, 35.5, 36.4, 36, 40.8, 34.2, 30.1, 35.6), wt_kg = c(0.165, 
0.1412, 0.1043, 0.1225, 0.1247, 0.1099, 0.087, 0.1176, 0.1431, 
0.1041, 0.1213, 0.0937, 0.0856, 0.1255, 0.1099, 0.124, 0.1361, 
0.1384, 0.1021, 0.1113, 0.12, 0.1513, 0.1448, 0.0978, 0.138, 
0.1232, 0.0942, 0.1881, 0.1038, 0.3498, 0.1122, 0.094, 0.1268, 
0.1009, 0.1358, 0.12, 0.2388, 0.1456, 0.0982, 0.0903, 0.1005, 
0.1252, 0.1138, 0.1476, 0.1326, 0.0849, 0.108, 0.0996, 0.1229, 
0.1279, 0.0874, 0.1492, 0.1416, 0.1187, 0.193, 0.1383, 0.1125, 
0.1449, 0.0941, 0.1265, 0.1823, 0.1455, 0.0948, 0.1603, 0.1119, 
0.1124, 0.1641, 0.1259, 0.116, 0.086, 0.1361, 0.1284, 0.1403, 
0.1461, 0.1195, 0.5985, 0.3099, 0.1829, 0.2688, 0.2244, 0.6214, 
0.1554, 0.2475, 0.2976, 0.0683, 0.1731, 0.4751, 0.356, 0.1388, 
0.5939, 0.2122, 0.2784, 0.3689, 0.3127, 0.2284, 0.1775, 0.6697, 
0.5998, 0.8374, 0.5647, 0.3187, 0.1704, 0.1619, 0.1413, 0.1621, 
0.3577, 0.319, 0.2846, 0.1815, 0.0776, 0.2567, 0.4483, 0.1337, 
0.2798, 0.202, 0.1847, 0.1758, 0.1659, 0.1828, 0.3669, 0.3211, 
0.1863, 0.2559, 0.6901, 0.6483, 0.0922, 0.088, 0.099, 0.0836, 
0.094, 0.099, 0.1157, 0.1138, 0.1046, 0.0495, 0.0513, 0.119, 
0.0761, 0.0936, 0.0564, 0.1438, 0.0636, 0.1134, 0.0641, 0.0594, 
0.0713, 0.0733, 0.0804, 0.0853, 0.0689, 0.118, 0.0892, 0.0875, 
0.0837, 0.0807, 0.1065, 0.1385, 0.1163, 0.1305, 0.0923, 0.0974, 
0.1176, 0.0848, 0.1059, 0.157, 0.0932, 0.1127, 0.0779, 0.1048, 
0.1327, 0.1688, 0.1096, 0.1304, 0.1173, 0.115, 0.0742, 0.129, 
0.0629, 0.0992, 0.0758, 0.0722, 0.0535, 0.0958, 0.1721, 0.1017, 
0.0766, 0.1099, 0.152, 0.128, 0.1185, 0.065, 0.1176, 0.0565, 
0.0866, 0.163, 0.12, 0.0825, 0.1149, 0.0839, 0.0587, 0.1335, 
0.0968, 0.0901, 0.1073, 0.0802, 0.0744, 0.1493, 0.1384, 0.1128, 
0.0738, 0.1146, 0.1108, 0.08, 0.1285, 0.0829, 0.1116, 0.1368, 
0.2348, 0.0995, 0.0989, 0.0748, 0.1484, 0.0629, 0.0823, 0.075, 
0.1768, 0.0607, 0.1142, 0.1289, 0.1506, 0.1742, 0.0626, 0.1187, 
0.1509, 0.1144, 0.0928, 0.0946, 0.099, 0.0717, 0.1318, 0.1025, 
0.093, 0.0972, 0.1325, 0.1209, 0.0943, 0.1006, 0.1073, 0.1336, 
0.1439, 0.1066, 0.0765, 0.0673, 0.1082, 0.0923, 0.1139, 0.068, 
0.0758, 0.0868, 0.1499, 0.0779, 0.0794, 0.0575, 0.1392, 0.0915, 
0.0845, 0.086, 0.084, 0.1049, 0.1486, 0.1573, 0.177, 0.1319, 
0.13, 0.0872, 0.388, 0.4751, 0.2898, 0.2931, 0.2663, 0.2838, 
0.3494, 0.3675, 0.4342, 0.2907, 0.3072, 0.2815, 0.2761, 0.1945, 
0.3512, 0.615, 0.2195, 0.4818, 0.3684, 0.4056, 0.2841, 0.1617, 
0.3425, 0.288, 0.1962, 0.1285, 0.1553, 0.1708, 0.1332, 0.1167, 
0.1491, 0.2028, 0.1267, 0.2406, 0.1257, 0.1499, 0.1559, 0.1895, 
0.1508, 0.1111, 0.1274, 0.1675, 0.2324, 0.1732, 0.1491, 0.1568, 
0.1465, 0.1548, 0.1245, 0.1399, 0.0855, 0.1151, 0.1612, 0.1693, 
0.1493, 0.1208, 0.088, 0.1106, 0.0654, 0.0827, 0.0794, 0.1331, 
0.0834, 0.0837, 0.0619, 0.092, 0.1397, 0.071, 0.1035, 0.0676, 
0.0729, 0.0906, 0.064, 0.0985, 0.0823, 0.1206, 0.155, 0.1438, 
0.1357, 0.1695, 0.0834, 0.1359, 0.1289, 0.0764, 0.1249, 0.0775, 
0.1139, 0.104, 0.1566, 0.1069, 0.0869, 0.1376, 0.1223, 0.105, 
0.0996, 0.1356, 0.1335, 0.0951, 0.2162, 0.1744, 0.4547, 0.5789, 
0.5555, 0.3899, 0.5037, 0.4281, 0.486, 1.0209, 0.5855, 0.5312, 
0.488, 0.3133, 0.5054, 0.3724, 0.59, 0.8119, 0.3811, 0.797, 0.5139, 
0.348, 0.7722, 0.743, 0.548, 0.8791, 0.9054, 0.5392, 0.4333, 
0.5314, 0.4976, 0.5953, 0.4288, 0.5179, 0.5634, 0.5331, 0.4371, 
0.5709, 0.5065, 0.8047, 0.5368, 0.5657, 0.5816, 0.4763, 0.5907, 
0.533, 0.4384, 0.4949, 0.7277, 0.4445, 0.4894, 0.4655, 0.5384, 
0.5106, 0.3343, 0.5186, 0.5262, 0.5311, 0.495, 0.4691, 0.3465, 
0.5558, 0.5975, 0.4768, 0.4802, 0.4573, 0.4037, 0.3316, 0.5152, 
0.4673, 0.2356, 0.2905, 0.5672, 0.2097, 0.2216, 0.7384, 0.4089, 
0.6159, 0.5219, 0.2866, 0.2443, 0.2071, 0.3658, 0.5861, 0.5021, 
0.6953, 0.5053, 0.3978, 0.3853, 0.6207, 0.2944, 0.507, 0.4412, 
0.3424, 0.6597, 0.5892, 0.3295, 0.6505, 0.9334, 0.6674, 0.4919, 
0.8392, 0.9123, 0.813, 0.8223, 0.5801, 0.5745, 0.5148, 0.8514, 
0.5563, 0.6417, 0.6445, 0.5701, 0.4186, 0.8303, 0.46, 0.6041, 
0.6537, 0.5221, 0.4782, 0.5657, 0.6499, 0.6667, 0.9074, 0.555, 
0.6696, 0.6083)), .Names = c("length_cm", "wt_kg"), row.names = c(NA, 
500L), class = "data.frame")
```

The relationship between length and weight is not linear.  Unfortunately I could not include the whole data set here but when the whole data set is used a gam provides the best fit, unlike in this subset where loess is suggested. 
I would like to focus on gam since an answer that works for the whole data set is what I am after.
It is obvious, even in the subset provided, that my data has some outliers, in the example data set (df) there are at least two obvious outliers.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=wt_kg, y=length_cm))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x), size = 1)
```

Moving forward with a gam approach I would like to generate the prediction interval so that I can identify which points fall in and out of say the 95% prediction interval.
This is extremely simple to do with a linear regression using predict:

```
l_model <- lm(wt_kg ~ length_cm, data=df)
df <- cbind(df, predict(l_model, interval = "prediction"))
```

Then simply plotting the upper and lower bounds of the interval

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=wt_kg, x=length_cm)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), 
              fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point()
```

But I can't seem to find a similar approach that works when using gam instead of lm.  I have tried predict.gam from the mgcv package with no success.

```
library(mgcv)
df_model <- gam(wt_kg ~ length_cm, data=df)
gam_pred <- cbind(df, mgcv::predict.gam(df_model))
```

I don't get any errors when running this however what i get back is a single col of data which I am unsure how to interpret. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly did your code look like when you tried to use `predict.gam()`? What did your call to `gam()` look like? What errors did you get exactly?

Comment: I have edited the post to include my calls to gam() and predict.gam()

Answer (score -1):

I think that part of your code is:

```
    require(broom)
require(gam)

mod <- gam(wt_kg ~ length_cm, data=df)

pred <- augment(mod)
```

But i dont understand the second ggplot2. **"Pred"** has the fitted value and others features about your regression, mainly **.resid**

Comment: You're using the wrong `gam` here, but **broom** happens to work for `mgcv::gam()` also.